# How to validate positional notation placeholders in format strings with msgfmt?

Tags: c++, c, msgfmt

When using printf-like format strings in a translated text `msgfmt --check` checks that the translation still contains the placeholders. For example, running `xgettext` on the following code

```
printf( gettext( "string: %s, int: %d" ), str, i )
```

produces a `.po` file with a `msgid` flagged as `c-format` and whose value is `"string: %s, int: %d"`. If the translator forgets either `%s` or `%d` in the translation then `msgfmt` complains:

> number of format specifications in 'msgid' and 'msgstr' does not match

Unfortunately this check does not apply to format strings using positional notation, like

```
boost::format( gettext( "string: %1%, int %2%" ) ) % str % i
```

How can I validate the presence of the positional notation placeholders in my translations?

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answer, but maybe following solution could solve your problem:

`boost::format( gettext( "string: %1$s, int %2$d" ) ) % str % i;`